# How to build kiosk using windows platform?

Tags: windows, kiosk

I was making an android app where we had a webcam plugged in to a tablet, a Samsung Galaxy Tab A, and when we were almost done with the app, we noticed that when we were recording using the webcam, we were getting a lag in the video and the audio. We thought it might be the camera so we hooked it up to my laptop and opened up the default camera application. When we recorded a video with this application, the video was PERFECT. We decided we will have to build something on a windows platform instead of android since we aren't getting the quality we want with that tablet. My question is, how can we build this, sort of, "kiosk" program on windows? What software would we need? What programming language would we need? Please excuse me if this isn't the place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What software would we need? What programming language would we need? 
>   To make windows kiosk you only need to configure windows. As kiosk program you can use absolutely any language.

Windows config:

- Create user for kiosk mode
- Set next registry key for this user as path to your application:

Windows XP/7:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\your\\application.exe>"
```

Windows 8 and later:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\your\\application.exe>"
```

Autologin for kiosk user:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon] 
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"ForceAutoLogon"="1"
"DefaultUserName"="kiosk"
"DefaultDomainName"="<place here pc hostname>"
"DefaultPassword"=""
```

*[Option]* If you need to disable Ctrl+Alt+Del, then use this registry key value ("") or you can place there own application:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe]
"Debugger"="\"\""
```

Create kiosk user with your application as shell and create/activate admin with password. With autologin to load as admin: press shift when windows loading and before autologin or while logging out - windows will show users list. Or, you can not set autologin and windows will show 2 users: admin and kiosk user with your software.